# ObjectChoiceField modifies either screen height or scroll

Tags: blackberry

I have two choices, one of them set Choices to another one when I select an option.

When I select an option, I calling in fieldChanged method a function that set new options to another ObjectChoiceField depending the selected option.

The problem is that the scroll decreases its height or the screen loses height and some fields at the bottom are hidden.

Please, any idea?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Not clear why this is a problem.  Normally people will just scroll to see the Fields at the bottom.  Or are you saying there are too many options?

Comment: Sorry about my poor explanation, for example: My screen has a blue background.  When I select a option and update another ObjectChoiceField with options from any place I realize that at bottom of the screen the blue background it's becoming white like if I cut a line of 30px.  So, I think it's decreasing screen size when I update the ObjectChoiceField.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your 'Background', and/or the definition of the Managers involved.  Have you reviewed this: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/MainScreen-explained/ta-p/606644

Comment: I have resolved the problem adding a global VerticalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL) to screen and overriding add() method to use verticalManager.  Thank you brother!